# Save picture using ContentResolver to Picutes sub-folder and prevent scanning by gallery

Tags: android, android-contentresolver, mediastore

For my app I have sub-folder in `Pictures/` to save app pictures.

I'm using ContentResolver and the following code to insert new item:

```
val contentValues = ContentValues().apply {
  put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, fileName)
  put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DOCUMENT_ID, fileName)
  put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, mimeType)
  put(
      MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH,
      "$mediaDirectory${File.separator}$appName")
} 
val uri = resolver.insert(
    MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
    contentValues)
```

I want pictures and my sub-folder to be accessible by user and it works fine this way.

But problem is that standard Gallery (either in emulator or in real phone) scans this folder and when I open gallery among all photos I see my app's photos, I'd like to avoid that.
I found only approach when I'd need to add some file named `.nomedia` to my app pictures sub-folder, but it doesn't look reliable.

Comment: `I'm using ContentResolver` No you use the MediaStore to get an uri.

Comment: You use the media store to get an uri. So the media store is the first one to know about your file. Gallery apps dont scan. The media store scans. Gallery apps query the media store for media files.

Comment: `they have sub-folder in /Pictures and no matter what photo user adds there - it doesn't appear in Gallery` I doubt that. Maybe on old devices where you could put a .nomedia file in a folder whereupon that folder was not scanned.

Comment: @blackapps thank you for clarification! Probably I made mistake about other apps logic, looks like they save to app-specific storage by default and provide feature to 'save to gallery' for user and only 'saved' pictures appear in gallery. I'll need to rework logic this way to avoid duplicated photos in gallery in case user picks one from gallery.